# What LibGDX viewport can stretch to a given size?

Tags: android, libgdx, viewport

I am trying to set up some smaller viewports for different stages inside my main viewport which is a StretchedViewport. So far, I have been doing it with ScalingViewports, with the scaling set to none, but today I tested it on a different device and I noticed the viewport's size did not stretch to the size relative to my main one's. To give you better image of how they are set up here is the code I am using.

```
viewport = new StretchViewport(720, 1280, cam);//the main viewport
viewport.apply();
cam.position.set(cam.viewportWidth / 2, cam.viewportHeight / 2,0);
secondaryViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.none, 480, 675);//the smaller ones sized relative to the main one
coinInsertionViewport = new ScalingViewport(Scaling.none, 200, 69);
```

What viewport can stretch to a given size relative to the StretchViewport's? StretchViewport stretches to whole screen, so it won't help me.

Comment: A viewport can't be "inside" another viewport. OpenGL doesn't nest them. Every one is defined in screen coordinates and only one can be applied at a time. You can explicitly set its dimensions to be within those of some other Viewport you've created, of course. You'll have to describe in detail what you're trying to achieve for us to understand what you want.

Comment: Say I am making a main StretchViewport, as in the example above, with the dimensions of 720 and 1280. How would I another viewport with the size of, let's say 450x700, that keeps this size relative to the main StretchViewport?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict drawing area to a part of the screen the use `setScreenBounds()` method of the viewport.

This will only allow you to draw in the left half of the screen

```
viewport.setScreenBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Comment: But what if I want to restrict it in a certain area, relative to the screen size? Do I simply use Gdx.graphics.getWidth() and Gdx.graphics.getHeight() and then do the math in order to achieve the exct size I want?

Comment: Yes you must use math to find the restricted area you want.

Comment: Ok, but what kind of viewport should I use?

Comment: I have tried sizing and positioning the smaller viewports relative to the system's width and height, but something is wrong. Here is how it looks on 2 different phones (the left one is 1980x1080 and the other one is 1280x720) http://imgur.com/a/Myq4Q. The item I used for testing in these images is that grey claw.